# How to draw polyline with negative coordinates in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, graphics2d, java-2d

I want to draw polyline with positive and negative coordinates.

> e.g. 
> 125,66
> 126,62
> -128,59
> -127,55
> -125,51
> -124,47
> -122,43
> -121,40
> -119,38
> -118,36
> These are the sample coordinate to draw the polyline in Jframe.
> After drawing the polyline it will show the line for positive coordinates only.

```
int j =0;
System.out.println(imageByteArray.length);
int[] x = new int [imageByteArray.length/2];
int[] y = new int [imageByteArray.length/2];
for (int i = 0; i <= imageByteArray.length-1;) 
{
    System.out.println(imageByteArray[i] +","+imageByteArray[i+1]);
    int s1 = imageByteArray[i];
    int s2 = imageByteArray[i+1];
    
    j++;
    i = i+2;
    
}

gp.drawPolyline( x, y, j );
```

Please help me to understand how we can draw polyline with such coordinates using java technology.

Comment: How are you trying to draw it? Do you have any code to show? Why would the coordinates be negative?

Comment: Don't post code in a comment. Update you question with the code so it is readable. You haven't answered the question as to why the coordinates would be negative. Negative values imply that you don't want the polygon to be visible. One solution would be to iterate through the array to find the largest negative value. Then you get the absolute value of that number and add the value to all coordinates to make all the coordinates positive. Then you draw the polygon. You could then use the Graphcis.translate to shift the polygon if required. Post an [mre] if you need more help.

Comment: Highlighted example section

Comment: I have added all necessary details which required for this question. In the given question i have added sample inputs and the issue which i am facing. Kindly reopen it so that i can get the answer for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your drawing panel (JPanel) is 400 x 400 pixels.

Let's take your polyline.  I'm assuming these are x, y coordinates.

```
 125, 66
 126, 62
-128, 59
-127, 55
-125, 51
-124, 47
-122, 43
-121, 40
-119, 38
-118, 36
```

The y coordinates range from 36 to 66.  These coordinates fit easily in the 0 to 399 range of our drawing panel.

The x coordinates range from -128 to 126.  These coordinates don't fit in the 0 to 399 range of our drawing panel.

The absolute difference between the minimum and the maximum x value is 254.  254 is less than the 400 pixels we have to work with.

Therefore, by adding 128 to each x coordinate, we can translate the polyline into something that can be drawn on our 400 x 400 drawing panel.

Comment: I have added 328 for negative coordinates and 128 for positive coordinates.
Post that i am able to able to generate polyline as expected.
Thanks @Gilbert Le Blanc for the help.

Comment: @Yogesh, *I have added 328 for negative coordinates and 128 for positive coordinates* - no, that is not the proper solution. You need to add the same value to all "x" coordinates. In my comment above I explained how you calculate the value to add. "328, is just some random number and should not be used.

Comment: Sorry... Typing mistake Its 384. I have tried with 128 but it was not drawn as expected then I have tried with multiple of 128 i.e 254 , 384. Addition of 384 for negative coordinates works for me.